# Multiline REGEX - match only the first line, ignore the rest of lines

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Here is the method to get remote SMTP server name:

```
public static String getMTAName(String data) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d{3}[ -](.*?)( .*)*$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group(1);
    }

    return "undefined";
}
```

The problem is that if I pass multiline response like:

```
String s = "220-xsistema.lt ESMTPSA XMailServer 1.2 service ready\r\n220 Some other info";
System.out.println(getMTAName(s));
```

The output is "undefined". But if:

```
s = "220-xsistema.lt ESMTPSA XMailServer 1.2 service ready";
```

Then everything works fine - the output is "xsistema.lt". My question is - how to match only the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` by default does not match `newline`.So use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` or use `DOTALL` flag,

`Pattern.DOTALL` or `(?s)` tells Java to allow the dot to match newline characters, too.

`Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^\\d{3}[ -](.*?)( .*)*$", Pattern.DOTALL);`

Comment: Yes, it works. Could you write a real example how to use `DOTALL` flag?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `.` doesn't match line break characters such as line feeds and carriage returns. You need to turn this feature on, easiest way would be the inline [**`(?s)`** (*dotall*)](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall) mode modifier.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)^\d{3}[ -](.*?)( .*)*$");
```

Comment: No, it does not work if `s = "220 xsistema.lt";`. Here we can expect various scenarios of  SMTP servers response.

Comment: You could replace the second group to `(?: .*)?`